# Android Compose remember affects other remember change

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have the next hierarchy:

- WalletDetailsScreen

  - WalletDetailsView

    - SubWalletView
    - DefaultOutlinedButton

1st `remember` **domainsVisible** is declared in WalletDetailsScreen. Callback is propagated to `DefaultOutlinedButton`'s onClick.
2nd `remember` **copyToClipboardClicked** is declared in SubWalletView.

What happens:

1. User opens the screen.
2. User taps copy button at first (SubWalletView). (2nd remember)
3. User taps DefaultOutlinedButton then. 1st remember is changed **AND 2ND ONE IS CHANGED AS WELL!**

Code:

```
@Composable
fun WalletDetailsScreen(
    snackbarController: SnackbarController,
    wallet: Wallet,
    onNavIconClicked: () -> Unit
) {
    // CHANGING THIS REMEMBER CHANGES 2ND ONE (BUT ONLY IF 2ND WAS FIRED AT LEAST ONCE)
    val domainsVisible = rememberMutableStateOf(key = "domains_visible_btn", value = false)

        WalletDetailsView(
            snackbarController = snackbarController,
            wallet = wallet,
            domainsVisible = domainsVisible.value,
            domainsCount = 0
        ) {
            domainsVisible.toggle()
        }
}

@Composable
private fun WalletDetailsView(
    snackbarController: SnackbarController,
    wallet: Wallet,
    domainsVisible: Boolean,
    domainsCount: Int,
    onDomainsVisibilityClicked: () -> Unit
) {
        Column {
            wallet.subWallets.forEach { subWallet ->
                SubWalletView(snackbarController = snackbarController, subWallet = subWallet)
            }
            
            // 1st REMEMBER IS CHANGED HERE 
            DefaultOutlinedButton(text = text, onClick = onDomainsVisibilityClicked) 
        }
}

@Composable
private fun SubWalletView(
    snackbarController: SnackbarController,
    subWallet: SubWallet
) {
    // 2ND REMEMBER
    val copyToClipboardClicked = rememberMutableStateOf(key = "copy_btn", value = false)
    if (copyToClipboardClicked.value) {
        CopyToClipboard(text = subWallet.address)
    }

            // 2ND REMEMBER IS CHANGED HERE
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .clickable { copyToClipboardClicked.toggle() } 
                    .padding(start = 15.dp, top = 5.dp, bottom = 5.dp, end = 5.dp)
            ) {
                // just icon here
            }
}
```

Helpers:

```
@Composable
fun <T> rememberMutableStateOf(
    key: String,
    value: T,
    policy: SnapshotMutationPolicy<T> = structuralEqualityPolicy()
) = remember(key) { mutableStateOf(value, policy) }

fun MutableState<Boolean>.toggle() {
    value = !value
}
```

I've tried to add keys to remember but it hasn't helped. Any ideas why changing one remember affects another? This shouldn't happen.

Comment: From what you describe it looks like the `copyToClipboardClicked` is toggled in the `clickable` modifier inside the `SubWalletView` and is toggled in step 2.

Comment: @chuckj that's correct, `copyToClipboardClicked` is toggled in the `clickable` inside the `SubWalletView`

Comment: there're a lot of unresolved references: `SnackbarController`, `Wallet`, etc. Please provide a runnable code, perfectly as minimalistic as you could. I'm using a clear project to reproduce "bugs", often solution if found while trying to make sample code for stackoverflow =)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I figured out what's going on.
Second `remember` isn't changed actually.
But I rely on it to show shackbar:

```
    if (copyToClipboardClicked.value) {
        CopyToClipboard(text = subWallet.address)
        ShowSnackbar(...)
        copyToClipboardClicked.toggle() // <--- WE NEED THIS
    }
```

And the missed part is that I need to switch flag off. I hadn't done it and that's why the if was triggered on each recomposition.